# Find first occurrence of a string in a String array in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, duplicates

I have an empty string array. I push into it new strings, and I do this one by one. Then, it will happen that the string I'm pushing is already in the array, and I want to find the index of that original string and split the array in the range:

`[start, index_of_firstString]`.

So if we have:

```
myArray: string[] = [];

function(myString: string) {
this.myArray.push(myString);
}
```

What could be a good solution? I need to check for duplicates every time I push a new string.

Comment: You can use indexOf(): `['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].indexOf('bar'); // 1`. -1 indicates the value isn't in the array. Any other number is the index in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use of `indexOf` function to get the first occurence of your string in your strings array,

```js
var cars = ['ferrari','Audi','ferrari']

console.log(cars.indexOf('ferrari'))
```